# how do i make ungrouped datasets with charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

what i need is for each dataset to be separate from the other, but, i'm not finding a way to do it, whenever i google it, i find the exact oposite, i've seen that in the API there is a option called grouped, but no matter where i set it to false, i can't get it to work

i'm using charts.js v2

this is what i have:
[chart grouped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtV6v.png)

this is what i want to achive (made with photoshop): [chart ungrouped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUdhj.png)

this is my current chart code

note that i get names, data and max from a rpc procedure

you can replace it with `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]` for names

`[1,5,10,12]` for `Positive Stats` data

`[2,2,5,10]`  for `Negative Stats` data

and `20` as the max

```
var labels = getNames()
var data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
  {
    label: 'Positive Stats',
    data: getPositiveStats(),
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(138,252,54,1)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgb(138,252,54)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'Negative Stats',
    data: getNegativeStats(),
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(222,0,0,1)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgb(222,0,0)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        display: true,
        max: parseInt(max),
        beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
      }
    }
  }
};

var chart = new Chart(
  canvas,
  config
)
```

### things i have tried

```
var data = {
  grouped:false,
  labels: labels,
  ...
}
```

```
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
  // grouped:false, //tried it here
    scales: {
    // grouped:false, //and here here
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

```
const grouped = false //might as well try, didn't work ofc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is give the bars different x coordinates. Right now you get the "x" from labels, so your datasets get the same "x" and that's why they are grouped. remove `labels: labels` and in `data` give an array of objects like this: `{"x": something, "y": 123123213}`

I have a fiddle about this here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/ynv8dojx/11/)